# springboot project,database using mysql in xampp

Tags: spring-boot, xampp

public Integer Id;
public String CasesName;

that my table's entities

{
"Id": 0,
"CasesName": "string",
"id": 0,
"casesName": "string"
}
that what i get when i test Api in swagger or postman

help me for that error please